# global methods or functions in python

Tags: python

I am making a small game in Python using `pythonista` on my ipad.
I made a vector class that contains the coordinates and several functions to add, get a length, set a length. I have another class called Game in which I have my game variables and functions. I can define a vector lets say

```
self.pos=vector(200,200)
```

But if I want to work out the length, I can't call the `getlength` function because I'm not in the right class.

Example (I've taken out most of the code):

```
class vector(objet):
    def __init(self,x,y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y

   def getlength(self):
       return sqrt(self.x**2+self.y**2)

  def addvec(self,a,b):
   return vector(a.x+b.x,a.y,b.y)


class Game(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.pos=vector(200,200)
        self.pos=vector(200,200)

    def loop(self):
        ## here i want something like d= length of self.pos !!

class MyScene(Scene):
    def setup(self):
        self.game=Game()

    def draw(self):
        self.game.loop()  

run(MyScene())
```

Thanks,
Nicolas

EDIT :  the call

```
sum=addvec(self.pos,self.pos2)
```

obviously doesn't work because self is a Game class. How can I do it?

Comment: `self.pos.getlength`? You neither want nor need it to be a global function - it's a useful *instance method*.

Comment: Please use 4 spaces to set an indentation level. UPD: That's better.

Comment: What happens when you try to call the `getlength` method?

Comment: `__init` should be `__init__`

Comment: `objet` should be `object`

Comment: Where do you want to call the method? Also, it doesn't appear that `getlength` needs the `v` argument; you want to return a value based on `self.x` and `self.y`, not `v.x` and `v.y`.

Comment: This may not be welcome advice, but have you considered working through a couple python tutorials before attempting a game?

Answer (score 4):

Why do you use two arguments for the getLength function? The second one is a vector (I assume) so it would be better to use:

```
def getLength(self):
    return sqrt(self.x**2+self.y**2)
```

and then just call:

```
d = self.pos.getLength()
```

If you would want to add two vectors together you would do something like this:

```
def add(self,other_vector):
    return vector(self.x+other_vector.x,self.y+other_vector.y)
```

so you would call:

```
sum = self.pos.add(some_other_vector)
```

BTW: Classes should always be written in CamelCase. And maybe you should read something about object oriented programming in python: http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/python-from-scratch-object-oriented-programming--net-21476

Comment: Thanks, that works !
Sorry if I and not very good at this...if I want to add two vectors with a function in the vector class.
'code'
def addvec(self,a,b):
  return vector(a.x+b.x,a.y,b.y)

the call sum=addvec(self.pos,self.pos2) obviously doesn't work because self is a Game class. How can I do it?